# Terraform: Referencing resources created in for_each in another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform, amazon-route53

When I had a single hosted zone it was easy for me to create the zone and then create the NS records for the zone in the delegating account by referencing the hosted zone by name.

- Edit To try to avoid confusion this is what I wanted to achieve but for multiple hosted zones and the owner of the domain is a management account: https://dev.to/arswaw/create-a-subdomain-in-amazon-route53-in-2-minutes-3hf0

Now I need to create multiple hosted zones and pass the nameserver records back to the parent account and I am not sure if its possible (or how if it is) to reference multiple resources. Reading this probably doesn't make a whole lot of sense, so the code below is as far as I have got.

I now have a `for_each` loop which will loop over a list of strings and create a hosted zone for each string, and I want to then create corresponding NS records in another account, notice that I am using a separate provider `provider = aws.management_account` to connect to the management account and this works fine for a single hosted zone.

I do not know how to reference the hosted zones, is there some syntax for this or is my approach wrong?

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "public_hosted_zone" {
  for_each = local.aws_zones
  name     = "${each.value}.${var.domain}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "ns_records" {
  for_each        = local.aws_zones
  provider        = aws.management_account
  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = "${each.value}.${var.domain}"
  ttl             = 30
  type            = "NS"
  zone_id         = data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_hosted_zone_id.value

  records = [
    aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone.name_servers[0], # Here is my old code which works for a single hosted zone but I cannot work out how to reference multiples created above
    aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone.name_servers[1],
    aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone.name_servers[2],
    aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone.name_servers[3]
  ]
}
```

Comment: `records = aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone.name_servers` should work in TF >= 0.12

Comment: A very slight adjustment (failed first build)

 `records = aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone[each.key].name_servers `

Can you tell me how this works? When I view the plan output terraform is creating the hosted zones first and then the route53 records, how does it tie the two up and use the `each.key` from the route53 record `for_each` to properly reference the resources created in the `aws_route53_zone`?

Comment: What is the form of `local.aws_zones`?

Comment: It looks like this `["dev", "test", "qa"]`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It looks like you're trying to set NS records for a zone to the name servers that already exist for the zone. Firstly, this isn't how you set name servers for a route53 zone and secondly you don't actually need to do anything here as you'd see if you looked at your zone records after creating the zone.

Comment: Actually what I am doing is passing the nameservers to the delegating account so I do need to do this. Sure the name server records exist in the account they were created in.... hence I am able to reference them as per my example above, I dont need to look to realise this... also I can see them for a single domain in my management account hosted zone, I am using a separate provider entry for the management account to pass those back as this account owns the domain, for DNS delegation. I have updated the question as it wasnt clear enough, although this is now answered and the answer works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since your `local.aws_zones` is set ["dev", "test", "qa"], your `aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone` will be a map with keys "dev", "test", "qa".

Therefore, to use it in your `aws_route53_record`, you can try:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "ns_records" {
  for_each        = local.aws_zones

  # other attributes

  records = aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone[each.key].name_servers
}
```

Comment: Where does this information appear in the official Terraform documentation?

Comment: @jtbandes https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances

Answer (score 9):

In this case it seems like your intent is to say "there is one zone per entry in `local.aws_zones` and then one NS recordset per zone".

In situations like that, a concise way to write that down is to use one resource as the `for_each` of the next, like this:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "public_hosted_zone" {
  for_each = local.aws_zones

  name = "${each.value}.${var.domain}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "ns_records" {
  provider = aws.management_account
  for_each = aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  ttl             = 30
  type            = "NS"
  zone_id         = data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_hosted_zone_id.value
  records         = each.value.name_servers
}
```

By using `for_each` inside `resource "aws_route53_zone" "public_hosted_zone"` you make `aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone` be a map from zone keys to zone objects, which is itself compatible with the expectations of `for_each` and so you can pass that map downstream to another resource.

An important advantage of this approach is that `each.value` in the `resource "aws_route53_record" "ns_records"` block is the corresponding zone object directly, and so we can write `each.value.name` to get the derived `name` argument from the zone without having to duplicate that expression again, and we can write `each.value.name_servers` to get the exported set of nameservers for each of the zones. That then avoids writing more complex expressions to look up zones by `each.key`, because Terraform has already done the necessary lookup to populate `each.value`.

Comment: This is a great tip, I was not aware that you could use a created set of resources to drive the `for_each` of another set of resources and so I loop over the original map all the time (`local.aws_zones`)